# How to Recover on a Failed Task?

Tags: scalaz

Given:

```
import scalaz.concurrent.Task
import scalaz._

val result: Task[String \/ Int] = Task { throw new RuntimeException("!")}
```

Then, I ran it to get a `RuntimeException`:

```
scala> result.unsafePerformSync
java.lang.RuntimeException: !
...
```

Does `Task` have an "equivalent" `Future#recover`, i.e. something like the following?

`def recover[A, B, C](t: Task[A], handleError: Throwable => B \/ C]: Task[B \/ C]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task#handle` (or alternatively `handleWith`) does the trick

```
  def f: String = {
    throw new RuntimeException()
    "I will fail"
  }
  Task(f).handle{ case _ ⇒ "recovered"}.run \\ recovered
```